# sql server bulk insert

Tags: sql-server

i want to insert csv file with special character
how can csv file to sql server database with special character

Answer (score 1):

[Sql bulk insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

Comment: alter procedure test_123
as
BULK
INSERT ExcelToDB
FROM 'D:\EtilizedataSaba211009.csv'
WITH (CODEPAGE = 'RAW',

 FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
 ROWS_PER_BATCH = 10000, TABLOCK)
GO
this procedure isnot working

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BULK INSERT T-SQL command (it also has a command line version):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188365.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Besides SQL BULK insert, you could also check out the SQL Server Integration Services, if you have to do this just once.

In SQL Server Management Studio, go to the Object Explorer, find your database, right click on it, and then choose "Tasks > Import Data". This brings up the SSIS wizard, which allows you to pick a source (your CSV file), a target (your SQL Server database+table), and it supports picking just certain fields, renaming them and much more.

For "do it once" operations, this is quite a nice and useful wizard.

Comment: However, if you have data in columns that might be larger than 50 characters, you need to adjust the column sizes. I've never yet imported a file this way where I didn't have to do that for at least one column.

Comment: Hmm.... I just inserted a large number of Excel sheets with columns of 255 chars of width - no manual intervention necessary.... (SSIS 2008)

Answer (score 0):

If you are programming in .NET you could use [CsvHelper](http://nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper) and the [BulkInserter](https://github.com/ronnieoverby/RonnieOverbyGrabBag/blob/master/BulkInserter.cs) class that I wrote.

Use CsvHelper to read the csv lines as CLR objects and BulkInserter will pump them into the database for you. Here's the [BulkInserter usage](https://github.com/ronnieoverby/RonnieOverbyGrabBag/wiki/Bulk-Inserter).

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a procedure in SQL which can be called every time you want to bulk insert or you can hardcode it.

The hardcoded BULK INSERT would be:

```
BULK   
INSERT *TableName*   
FROM *'FilePath'*   
WITH   
(   
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',   
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   
CODEPAGE = 'ACP'   
)   
GO
```

I have used this many times. I think it is better to use it as a procedure if you are going to use it quite a lot, but this means that you will need to create the procedure and call it in each query.

Answer (score -1):

Sql Bulk insert